# Bug Items in TFS with Scrum Template

Tags: tfs, scrum

How do you handle bug duplicates in tfs with scrum template? Do you use the state "delete" or do you first set the bug to "in progress"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about project management.

Answer (score 1):

I got some duplicates in the list of user stories too.
I simply use the state "Closed" with the description "Out of Scope", and I add a comment stating that the user story was closed because it was a duplicate.

Sounds good to add a reference to the original item.

I guess something like this can be done for bugs as well.

Answer (score 0):

That entirely depends on what you would try to achieve. I would suggest that you could simply set the duplicate to 'delete' possibly creating a link to the other bug.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an option to set it to a state of "duplicate" from its initial state. I agree with @mfloryan that you should link to the original bug.

If you let mek now which template you are using I may be able to revice this to be more specific.

Comment: Scrum for Team System: http://www.scrumforteamsystem.com/en/default.aspx
The state model of bug has only "not done", "in progress", "deleted", "ready for test" or "done". There are no options to describe the resolution of the bug, like "duplicated", "not fixed", "unable to reproduce" or "not a bug".